# Meteor BUILD FAILED

Tags: android, macos, cordova, meteor, android-emulator

i'm using mac os Captain Last version, i was building meteor project to get the apk file for android, all was going fine until this problem:

```
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While building Cordova app for platform Android:
   Error code 1 for command:                  
   /Users/tayechhoussem/Desktop/test2/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew
   with args:
   cdvBuildRelease,-b,/Users/tayechhoussem/Desktop/test2/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Comment: Is gradle installed?  Can you run `gradlew`?  How about running it with the mentioned arguments?

Comment: i just installed gradlew but it still the same problem

Comment: Try it with the args listed?

Comment: please can you specify more? because i'm not an expert

Comment: The lines after the error specify which program ran (`/Users/tayechhoussem/Desktop/test2/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew`) and which arguments where passed (`cdvBuildRelease,-b,/Users/tayechhoussem/Desktop/test2/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true`).  Try running the command manually with the same arguments by copying the full command line and adding each argument, replacing the commas with spaces, and see what happens.